# What can be added or remove in this dart class

Tags: flutter, dart

Please what could be the error in this dart class.

```
class Question {

  String questionText;
  bool questionAnswer;

  Question({String q, bool a}) {
    questionText = q;
    questionAnswer = a;
  }
}
```

Error log:

```
error: Non-nullable instance field 'questionText' must be initialized. (not_initialized_non_nullable_instance_field at [practice] lib\question.dart:5)
error: Non-nullable instance field 'questionAnswer' must be initialized. (not_initialized_non_nullable_instance_field at [practice] lib\question.dart:5)
```

[image: error image]

Answer (score 1):

```
class Question {
  String QuestionText;
  bool QuestionAnswer;

  Question(this.QuestionText, this.QuestionAnswer);
}
```

OR

```
class Question {
  late String QuestionText;
  late bool QuestionAnswer;

  // Question(this.QuestionText, this.QuestionAnswer);
  Question(String q, bool s) {
    QuestionAnswer = s;
    QuestionText = q;
  }
}
```

Comment: The first solution is the correct and idiomatic solution IMO (https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#do-use-initializing-formals-when-possible). However I would strongly caution against using the second solution, using `late` introduces potential for runtime errors and is completely unnecessary in this situation, see also https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-use-late-when-a-constructor-initializer-list-will-do

Comment: from android native java .always contructor initial first. so i mentioned here .better solution first and second most equal to first

Answer (score 0):

Make your fields nullable by adding **?** to the type.

```
class Question {

  String? questionText;
  bool? questionAnswer;

  Question({String q, bool a}) {
    questionText = q;
    questionAnswer = a;
  }
}
```